# Generate random images from user checkboxed selections

Tags: javascript, html, css, random

Hi I have two sets of code. The first one was made by a nice person on this site, and generates a random letter based on the selections checkboxed by the user.

The second is one I found online. It allows you to turn image links into checkboxes that can be checked and unchecked.

I am trying to combine these two codes so that I can have the program generate a random image (instead of a letter) based on an array of images (again instead of letters) that the user checkboxes. In short, I'm trying to get something like the first set of code that uses images instead of letters.

Then, the final thing I'm trying to do is add a range slider like so (https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GJ5U82DC2JX9) underneath each image. I want the user to be able to use the slider to "weight" the frequency of each checked image in the final randomization (with a range of 0 to 10).

Here is the first program in running form:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GJ5TXX8V9B7L

Here is the second program in running form:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GJ5TXEQM6HVI

I have tried intuitively copying and pasting from one set to the other, but I cant seem to get it even close to working the way I'd like. As for the weighting part, I am at a loss.

Thank you for any and all help, and if this is beyond the scope of help for this site I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like that?

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="formMatrix">
  <ul>
  </ul>

  <input id="randomSubmit" type="submit" value="Randomize">
</div>

<div id="result">
  <br />
  <br />
</div>
```

**JS Code:**

```
function updateTextInput(val, i) {
  document.getElementById('textInput-' + i).value = val;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  //put your image's links
  var images = ["http://townandcountryremovals.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/firefox-logo-200x200.png", "http://www.thebusinessofsports.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/facebook-icon-200x200.png", "http://tech21info.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/chrome-logo-200x200.png"];

  const form = document.getElementById("formMatrix");
  const submitBtn = document.getElementById("randomSubmit");
  const textResult = document.getElementById("result");

  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    form.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].innerHTML += ("<li><input type='checkbox' id='chk-" + i + "' /><label for='chk-" + i + "'><img id='img-" + i + "' src='" + images[i] + "'/><div class='ranges'><input type='range' id='range-" + i + "' min='0' max='10' value='0' onchange='updateTextInput(this.value, " + i + ");' /><input type='text' disabled='disabled' id='textInput-" + i + "' value='0'/></div></label></li>");
  }

  // We check the values on the submit click
  submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // Prevent it from *actually* submitting (e.g. refresh)
    e.preventDefault();
    // Grab *all* selected checkboxed into an array
    const items = document.querySelectorAll("#formMatrix input:checked");

    // Checking if it's not empty
    if (items.length > 0) {

      var array_items = [];

      // Convert object to array
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        array_items.push(items[i]);
      }

      // Add items by freq
      for (var i = 0; i < array_items.length; i++) {
        var n = parseInt(document.getElementById('textInput-' + array_items[i].id.split('-')[1]).value);
        for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
          array_items.splice(i + 1, 0, array_items[i]);
        }
        i = (i + n);
      }

      // Setting a random index from items[0] to items[items.length]
      var imgid = ('img-' + array_items[Math.floor(Math.random() * array_items.length)].id.split('-')[1]);

      textResult.innerHTML = ("<label><img id='imgResult' src='" + document.getElementById(imgid).src + "'/></label>");

    } else {
      // If not, we alert
      alert("Please choose at least 1 image");
    }

  });
});
```

**DEMO:**

https://jsfiddle.net/pr0mming/vfam3g05/31/

What I really don't understand is the slide part, do you mean that each image can have a "weighting" number, which means that the larger the number, the more frequent it should be output?

**UPDATE 1:**

The simplest way I saw was to temporarily work the array of selected images, then, if the weight is 10, 10 more images will be inserted into the array respecting the order and it will be chosen randomly.

**UPDATE 2:**

Last changes: https://jsfiddle.net/pr0mming/vfam3g05/33/

Comment: Yes exactly! So if an image with the slider at "2" would be far less likely to show up in the randomization than an image at "8". The sliders in the fiddle file you attached look exactly as I envisioned, but they don't seem to have any effect on the weighting of the random generation.

Comment: Ok bro, look my answer updated and the jsfiddle link

Comment: Wow thanks, that seems to work! And if I want to add more images to the program, should I put them where it says //put your image's links?

Comment: Yeah of course there is no problem, I put it like this so that you did not have to create everything in the html

Comment: Sorry couple more things if you are still there. Is there a way to remove the upper checkbox attached to each picture (just to make it look cleaner since each picture has two). And also how can I make the boxes that display the range numbers a little bigger?

Comment: use width and height property in the line 18 of the css file for display more big the input, for the checkboxes i hiden with css, review the jsfiddle again